# Is X12 being developed?

Tags: x11

I stumbled upon this page:
[Requirements for the Successor to the X11 Protocol - “X12”](https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/X12/)
Based on the description, it is clear that X12 must be an entirely new window system built from scratch, rather than an extension of X11.

So, my question is whether there are any actual ongoing efforts related to X12 development within any community, software alliance, etc?

**EDIT:**

I have checked the following question before asking this one:
[What happened with X12?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269248/what-happened-with-x12)
However, the questions itself, as well as the answers are actually about **x11** updates, which is why I don't believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: Quoting your linked page: "This is not to say that there's an X12 project. There isn't. But if one day there is..." On the other hand, there are other, more recent display servers, like Wayland and Mir

Comment: How about [Y](http://www.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/18619743.PDF)?

Comment: Thanks for the notice regarding alternative projects. Mir is discontinued, though.

Comment: The answer to [What's the story behind the name “X11”?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3055/79) addresses this to some extent. There is no X12 project because most of the features people really wanted could be added to X11; the successor to X11 is effectively Wayland, that’s what’s being developed (including by X developers).